# WordPress plugin dependency

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i am writing a WooCommerce extension where i want to check that if the user has already installed and activated WooCommerce, if not then show a notice to user to installed/activate WooCommerence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this function .

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active